# Cordova plugin with v7-appcompat dependency

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to add a dependency to the `android support v7 appcompat` library to my Cordova plugin. I've tried many ways of doing this, but nothing seems to do the trick. I'm really surprised that I haven't been able to find a tutorial for this on the Cordova website or anywhere for that matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there was a very simple solution to this problem. Previously, I had checked the contents of my Android Library Project directly my Cordova Plugin. My Cordova Plugin is really just a wrapper for iOS and Android with a native bridge class for each.

What I had tried to do was add the `appcompat-v7` dependency to my `plugin.xml`. That didn't work.

But because I distribute my Android Library Project as an `.aar` on central maven, I was able to modify my `plugin.xml` to simply include that file as a framework. Since my `.aar` had dependencies to `appcompat-v7` and other libraries specified in the accompanying `pom.xml`, the normal Cordova build process worked perfectly.

```
<platform name="android">
    <!--
      Your other plugin configuration options would go here.
    -->
    <framework src="com.your.package:your-artifact:1.0.0"/>
    <source-file src="src/android/YourBridge.java" target-dir="src/com/your/package/cordova"/>
</platform>
```

Comment: Do you know how to add dependency in my Android app module? I don't have a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

@Sky,
I think you are asking for for SDK 7 compatibility. If so, then you need to add to your `config.xml` the following line:

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
```

This article will have more details.
*PhoneGap 3.0 – Stuff You Should Know*
http://devgirl.org/2013/09/05/phonegap-3-0-stuff-you-should-know/

You can also Google: [phonegap CLI minSdkVersion](https://www.google.com/search?q=phonegap+CLI+minSdkVersion)

**If not, then please respond.**

Lastly, you might consider reading this:
*[Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)*

Jesse

Comment: To last editor, stackoverflow talks about courtesy to user. Which include addressing them directly. It should be clear (if it is not, to you) there are conflicting suggestions and rules within stackoverflow. You might consider that when you edit.

Comment: Thanks Jesse. Actually, I'm talking about the Android support v7 appcompat library. Cordova currently only supports down to API level 14 on Android anyway.

Comment: My sense is that this is the wrong place to get an answer. This forum is filled with newbies. I would try the [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/phonegap) instead. The answers are better.